# Cut last 30 seconds off ends of videos using ffmpeg in a batch file in Windows

Tags: video, ffmpeg

This is what I have so far:

```
for i in *.mp4; do ffprobe -show_format -i "%i"
```

// get duration, then need to somehow subtract 30 seconds, and marry these two commands

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -i "$i" -t %duration% "${i%.mp4}-cut.mp4
```

I thought it would be simple, ugh.. **why you no have *-endtrim* switch, ffmpeg?** or does it? Maybe another command line one like this can?

Comment: If you have found a solution to your question, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Post on behalf of the OP who solved the problem themselves:

**_trim.bat**:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.mp4) do (
call _trim2.bat "%%i"
)
```

**_trim2.bat**:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('_ffprobe -show_format -i %1 ^| find "duration"') do set _duration=%%a
set _duration=%_duration:~9%
for /f "delims=. tokens=1*" %%b in ('echo %_duration%') do set /a "_durS=%%b"
for /f "delims=. tokens=2*" %%c in ('echo %_duration%') do set "_durMS=%%c"
rem following line is seconds to cut
set /a "_durS-=30"
set "_newduration=%_durS%.%_durMS%"
set "_output=%~n1"
md _fixed
_ffmpeg -ss 0 -i %1 -t %_newduration% -c copy "_fixed\%_output%.mp4"
```

the processed filed will be put in **.\_fixed\samename.mp4** and will all be 30 seconds shorter.

Comment: More than 8 years later, and it still work like a charm. Thank you so much, Sir. At least for me as the first time try to use batch file, I'd be glad if there is an explanation what it do. Such as what does `tokens=*` ....  `%_duration:~9%` mean. (Need to google about that). The only thing I can understand is assumed the total video duration is 50secs... so my guess the `_durMS` value is 50, while the `_durS` value is -30. That makes `_newduration` ---> -30.50 = 20 secs which will be the output result. Thank you once again, Sir slhck.

Comment: @karma I only posted the solution on behalf of the original person asking the question. I have no experience with Windows batch scripts. `durS` is seconds and `durMS` is milliseconds. Then, 30 seconds are subtracted from `durS` to arrive at the new duration. `durMS` is kept as-is.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use this same exact method for some of files I have.

When I execute `_trim2.bat` it comes up with errors that Windows doesn't recognize `_ffprobe` and `_ffmpeg` (which of course it doesn't cause of underscores).

When I try to execute without underscores it gives an error for `ffprobe` and `ffmpeg` as following, respectively:

```
Missing argument for option 'i'
Unrecognized option '15.'.(duration is 15)
```

Comment: I am not sure whether this is an answer, or a follow-up issue.

Comment: It is a follow up question.I wasn't able to make a comment

Comment: You should ask your own question, using the button at the top of the page and link back to this question using the URL.

Answer (score 0):

[I hope this helps guys...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MXQR.png)
Probably too late for the above scenario but who ever will search... good day

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1119512)